# Time Complexity of the given nested loops

Tags: time-complexity

I have been told that the time complexity of this code is O(n),could you please explain me how is it so. The time complexity of the outer loop is log n,inner?

```
int fun(int n)
{
 int count = 0;
 for (int i = n; i > 0; i /= 2)
  for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
    count += 1;
return count;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's actually quite easy once you understand what the function does.

The inner loop basically adds i to count. So you can just reduce the code here to this:

```
int fun(int n) {
 int count = 0;
 for (int i = n; i > 0; i /= 2)
  count += i;
 return count;
}
```

So now what you have is it halves i and adds that half to count.
If you keep doing that you'll end up with a number close to n. If you'd do it with an infinitely accurate float representation of i and count you will actually get exactly n (though it will take you an infinite amount of steps).

For example, let's look at n=1000, these are the steps that will be taken:

```
i: 500    count: 500
i: 250    count: 750
i: 125    count: 875
i: 62     count: 937
i: 31     count: 968
i: 15     count: 983
i: 7      count: 990
i: 3      count: 993
i: 1      count: 994
```

The 6 that are missing from count in the end are rounding mistakes at i=125/2, i=31/2, i=15/2, i=7/2, i=3/3 and i=1/2.

So you can see, the complexity of that function is almost exactly n, which certainly makes it O(n).

Comment: The first loop count is missing in the n = 1000 example.  It should read something like 
(i: 1000      count: 1000), (i: 500        count: 1500) ...